# Cannot process PDF by Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-vision

I'm using Google Cloud Vision for PDF processing.
File is saved on Google Cloud Storage.
I'm using exactly same code from Google tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf.

But OCR is not executed and I'm getting this error: Error: Unsupported input file format.

File is in PDF format and has application/pdf Content Type.

I have no idea where problem is.

Comment: Is it possible this pdf file is not the result of a document scan,  but instead the output of some text processing program? OCR needs images as input.

Comment: Have you already tried the pdf file first in this example?

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/cloud-client/detect/resources

Comment: This error is common with different formats, such as HTML, so it's odd you would get this with a proper PDF. By any chance could you share a file that leads to reproduce the error? If it's not an input-related issue, then having the file can help to investigate further.